# How do get Aurelia to render my view after dynamically adding a custom element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, aurelia

When creating a custom element in the DOM and adding a respective view model which implements bindable from the aurelia-framework, my view renders perfectly.

custom element in DOM as so:

```
<!-- chatbox.html -->
<template>
...    
    <ul class="chat">
        <answer name="Reah Miyara" nickname="RM" text="Hello World"></answer>
    </ul>
...
    <button class="btn" click.trigger="addCustomElement()">Add</button>
...
</template>
```

Aurelia's magic rendering results in various children elements associated with the custom element in the DOM, when inspecting from the browser.

The issue arises when I am attempting to dynamically add additional custom elements to the DOM using jQuery like so...

```
// chatbox.js
addCustomElement() { 
    $('.chat').append('<answer name="Joe Smith" nickname="JS"></answer>');
}
```

Invoking this method using the button *(Aurelia's 'click.trigger')* indeed adds the custom element to the DOM, but **without** the various children elements which allows the custom element to be properly rendered in the view...

How do I properly dynamically add custom elements to the DOM or tell Aurelia to process a custom element which I have added so it renders in my view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a repeater and append a new item to the array the repeater is bound to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would modify as follows:

```
//chatbox.js
export class Chatbox {
   answers = [{
      name:'Reah Miyara',
      nickname:'RM'
   }];
   addCustomElement() {
      answers.push({
        name:'Joe Smith',
        nickname: 'JS'
      }];
   }
}
```

Then in your template, use a `repeat.for` on the `answers` property.  Aurelia's binding system will ensure that there is an `<answer>` tag for each element in the `answers` array.

```
<!-- chatbox.html -->
<template>
 ...
<ul class="chat">
  <answer repeat.for="answer of answers" name.bind="answer.name" nickname.bind="answer.nickname"></answer>
</ul>
<button class="btn" click.trigger="addCustomElement()">Add</button>
... 
</template>
```

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing!