# Aurelia - render custom element by name

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Suppose we have a custom element that renders a list of *something*. It is a selector element, so it does not atter how this *something* is rendered.

The problem is that this *something* is quite generic and there are custom elements to actually render it. For example, for countries we add a flag image, for general elements - a fontawesome icon, reputation for users, etc.

### What I would like to have

And now I would like to pass the name of the custom element I want to render *something* with. So instead of this

```
<selector data.one-way="options" selected.two-way="selected"></selector>
```

Have something like

```
<selector element="country" data.one-way="options" selected.two-way="selected"></selector>
```

And in the `selector` I would like to have

```
<${element} content.one-way="el" repeat.for="el of data"></${element}>
```

### What I get

Unfortunately, the code above renders as **htmlescaped**

```
<country content.one-way="el" repeat.for="el of data"></country>
```

### So,

Is there a more or less clean way to achieve that? Basically I would like to pass the specify custom elements I want to render in my selector custom element. [This post and the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595103/how-do-get-aurelia-to-render-my-view-after-dynamically-adding-a-custom-element-t) have nothing to do with my question.

Using `compose` as described [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/composition-aurelia-report-builder/)... well, it is an option, but I would like to have different custom elements and a slightly different logic in CustomElement js files.

Thanks!

## UPD

Well, there's an obvious way to do that by just adding something like a switch statement in the view

```
<country ... if.bind="el.type === 'country'"></country>
<phone ... if.bind="el.type === 'phone'"></phone>
<user ... if.bind="el.type === 'user'"></user>
```

But that would make the `selector` element dependent on `country`, `user` etc. So I would not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found couple possible solutions, they may seems more complicated then compose.

```
@bindable({
  name:'myProperty', //name of the property on the class
  attribute:'my-property', //name of the attribute in HTML
  changeHandler:'myPropertyChanged', //name of the method to invoke when the property changes
  defaultBindingMode: ONE_WAY, //default binding mode used with the .bind command
  defaultValue: undefined //default value of the property, if not bound or set in HTML
})
```

You can find more details there http://www.sitepoint.com/extending-html-aurelia-io-way/

Answer (score 3):

I believe easiest way is using the `compose` tag (like you've mentioned):

```
<compose model.bind="item" view-model="widgets/${item.type}"></compose>
```