# Dynamically add custom component to loaded DOM (aurelia.js)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is it possible to add a custom component to the DOM once it has already been loaded?

E.g. When clicking a button

Template

```
<template>
    <button click.delegate="add_component()"> Press me </button>
</template>
```

Viewmodel

```
@inject(Element)

export class App {

  constructor(element) {
      this.element = element;
  }

  function add_component() {
     var component = document.createElement('<customElement></customElement>');
     this.element.appendChild(component);
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is either going to be yes or no depending on what you are wanting to do. It isn't possible to do what you are doing the way you are showing, as Aurelia will not be looking for stuff being added to the DOM like that. But if you are using a repeater and the `compose` element, you could do something kind of like what you want to do. You might want to rethink what you're doing to see if there is a better way to accomplish it within the confines of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: adding to Ashley's comment, you can render components dynamically  the way its accomplished in aurelia-dialog or toasts pluging like aurelia-notify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do get Aurelia to render my view after dynamically adding a custom element to the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595103/how-do-get-aurelia-to-render-my-view-after-dynamically-adding-a-custom-element-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way to do that, actually. Depending on your actual need, you might get away with using the [compose element](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/4) if your need is to dynamically switch views.

Another approach is to use Aurelia's View Compiler to compile the markup into a view, then create a View Slot (there's some discussion on the topic in this [aurelia-templating GitHub issue](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/35)). With View Slots, it should be possible to dynamically add multiple views one after another.

However, if your actual need is anything close to your example, you can simply get away with something like this:

```
<template>
    <button click.delegate="add_component()"> Press me </button>
    <custom-element if.bind="hasCustomElement"></custom-element>
</template>
```

in the view and this:

```
export class App {
  @observable hasCustomElement = false;

  function add_component() {
      this.hasCustomElement = true;
  }
}
```

in the view model. The custom element will only be appended to the dom when the `if.bind` condition becomes `true` and removed if it becomes `false`.

Comment: The "compose element" link is new one: https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#composition